# How do I enable cross-origin websocket connections in Micronaut?

Tags: java, node.js, vue.js, websocket, micronaut

I'm trying to implement a new Micronaut microservice that will be a websocket server, let's say it runs on `http://localhost:8081` and the websocket is on `ws://localhost:8081/ws`.

The client will be the Vue.js UI running locally on a different domain, say `http://dev.domain.com:8080`.

When I click the UI button that will trigger the websocket connection and transmission of data, I get the following in Chrome:

`Common.umd.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/ws' failed:`

and the following in Firefox:

```
GET ws://localhost:8081/ws [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 412ms]

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8081/ws. Common.umd.js:formatted:3191:34
```

In Firefox it gives a `403` error, but in Chrome under the network tab it just says that the request to `ws://localhost:8081/ws` has `Finished`, without a status code. I'm not really sure what to make of this, but the `403` must be coming from the Micronaut server, correct?

The Micronaut websocket server code generally looks like (I left out the details because there is nothing mentioned in the Micronaut server access logs about a `403`, meaning the code isn't even reached):

```
@ServerWebSocket("/ws")
public class Server {

  /** Class logger. */
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server.class);

  /** Micronaut application context. */
  @Inject ApplicationContext ctx;
  
  /** Service configuration. */
  @Inject Configuration configuration;

  /** WebSocket broadcaster. */
  @Inject WebSocketBroadcaster broadcaster;

  /** The RabbitMQ message producer. */
  @Inject ApiProducer producer;
  

  /**
   * Handler for connection open event.
   *
   * @param session - the created WS session.
   * @return Publisher for the startup confirmation message.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
  @OnOpen
  public Publisher<String> onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
    ...
  }

  /**
   * Handler for message received event.
   *
   * @param message - the command payload
   * @param session - current WS session
   * @return Publisher for the response message.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @OnMessage
  public Publisher<String> onMessage(String message, WebSocketSession session) {
    ...
  }

  public Mono<String> onNotification(String notification, UUID correlationId) {
    ...
  }

  /**
   * Handler for connection close event.
   *
   * @param session - the WS session to be closed.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
  @OnClose
  public void onClose(WebSocketSession session) {
    ...
  }
}
```

On the Vue.js side, we are using the `vuex` `createStore` method in conjunction with the `VueNativeSock` module from the `vue-native-websocket-vue3` package.

Also on the Micronaut side, I have tried enabling processing of CORS requests using the following in the `application.yml` file:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: application-name
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
    port: 8081
```

However, this still doesn't work.

Some additional context: when I use `http://localhost:8080` as the UI domain and leave everything else the same, it connects and sends the data without issue. The problem only arises when the UI has a different domain, which would also be the case in production.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding the answer here: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/8560 in sdelamo's first Jan 11 comment.

I needed to use:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: application-name
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      configurations:
        ui:
          allowed-origins: "http://dev.domain.com:8080"
    port: 8081
```

This contradicts the documentation I read, which said that the configurations property was used to **restrict** cors access to specific domains not allow it.

Comment: You can check out this example. https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-cors-gradle-java.html. It says that using the cors and allowed-origins allows you to fine-grain the configuration